# What are these extra tubes underneath the kitchen sink faucet?

Tags: kitchens, faucet, kitchen-sink

I know the two tubes on the left side and right side of Arrow 1 are for cold and hot water. But what's the tube pointed by Arrow 1 for?

What about the tube pointed by Arrow 2?

It seems like Arrow 3 points to some kind of filter... I'm not totally sure. Can someone identify what those are used for?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your faucet has a removable sprayer part.

#2 is the hose that goes to this, it runs through the inside of the faucet and is attached to the faucet temperature valve on one and, and the handheld sprayer on the other end. If you pull the sprayer out, you should see this hose move.

#3 is just a weight. This is attached to the hose to help the sprayer slide back into its normal resting position in the faucet more easily / on its own.

Update based on comment: I forgot to mention #1, which is the same hose as #2. The end of #1 you can see is attached to the outlet of your faucet valve, is looped through the weight, and then we can see it go up again and into the faucet body.

Comment: ...and 1 might be any of: Water to refrigerator for icemaker/dispenser; water to dishwasher. The former is usually cold and the latter is usually hot. Or else 1 and 2 are the same tube with the #3 weight on it (I guess this picture is looking up, I thought it was down.)

Comment: Ah yes, i missed 1. I believe it is the same as 3, like you said.